# MVC 4 ActionResult JsonRegister

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

MVC 4 comes with 2 register methods in the AccountControllers:

- public ActionResult JsonRegister(RegisterModel model)
- public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)

Yet there is no way to specify which one to use in the view.

**Why do you need 2 methods to register a user in the same controller?**

Answer (score 0):

The templates that ship in the Beta will call the right method depending on whether you are using a modal dialog or the direct page to log in. That reference is hardcoded in the views and partials that make up the registration experience. Having said that, note that we will be removing the Ajax-baased login and registration workflows from the templates by the time RTM ships.

Comment: Why is Microsoft removing Ajax-baased login and registration workflows from the templates?