# Breakpoint doesn't hit after first click on Login and Register links

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a MVC4 web project in Visual Studio 2010.  I have breakpoints in AccountController.cs file for the following methods:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login()

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JsonLogin(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
```

None of these will get a hit after the first hit when clicking on a Login button.  Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe show us a more complete code? If it isn't hit, it didn't recognize the pattern...

Comment: I din't add any of my custom code.  It is all VS2010 MVC4 Project template generated code.

Comment: Wait, you're trying out the demo project and it doesn't work even though it wasn't changed?

Comment: The project itself works great!  I can add users and login.  The problem is with breakpoint not getting hit when clicking Login button second time.

Comment: the action of your form html tag, is it points to any of those methods?

Comment: do you get the following message: No symbols have been loaded for this document? when you hover over the breakpoint?

Comment: c0deNinja - No, I don't get that message.  As a matter of fact, it works first time around.

Comment: Well, I didn't add any code.  This is what I see in Login.cshtml    @using (Html.BeginForm((string)ViewBag.FormAction, "Account")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Log in was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.")

Comment: Had you said your breakpoints don't get hit every time but the very 1st time, that would have sounded natural to me because the default MVC App project template's modal dialogs are cached after they are opened for the 1st time. And for the 1st time these breakpoints must be hit. For the subsequent times, there are no request issued by the browser since the dialogs are cached -- and no breakpoint is hit. Can you confirm this is NOT what is happening with your app?

Comment: m1kael - Thanks, Good answer! That is what I expected.  They must have been cached by MVC project.  Having said that Microsoft seems to be removing these AJAX login methods in RTM version.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10794451/336829

Comment: WinFXGuy - you are welcome. Hope this helped.

Comment: You should have answered my question instead of commenting.

Comment: I commented because I wasn't answering your question but rather sought for a clarification. Now that it's clear it answered your question, I've copied the useful part of it to the answer section. And thanks for that comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default MVC4 App project template's modal dialogs are cached after they are opened for the 1st time. And for the 1st time these breakpoints must be hit. For the subsequent times, there are no request issued by the browser since the dialogs are cached -- and no breakpoint is hit.